# Place mysql results in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have a table that contains the name of the products and their corresponding quantity.

```
Product      Quantity      Delete
  A             10          Del
  B              5          Del
```

What I want to do is to place them in an array with the corresponding id of the product. I can get the product ID of the second product but I cannot get the ID of the first product. How can I fix it?

Here's the input form to the php code:

```
<table> 
   <tr>
       <td><input id="product1" type="text" value="A" name="product1"></td>
       <td><input id="quantity1" type="text" value="10" name="quantity1>
           <input type='hidden' name='htmlrow[]' value='1'> </td> //row number
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input id="product2" type="text" value="B" name="product2"></td>
       <td><input id="quantity2" type="text" value="5" name="quantity2">
           <input type='hidden' name='htmlrow[]' value='2'></td>//row number
   </tr>
</table>
```

php code:

```
$numberOfRows = $_POST["htmlrow"];
$r = end($numberOfRows);
for($i=1; $i<$r+1; $i++){  //r = number of rows
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_products WHERE productName = '".$_POST["product".$i]."'");     

       foreach($results as $product){
              $pID = $product->productID;
       } //I can only get the last product ID

       $orderItem = array(
                        'product' => $_POST["product".$i],
                        'productID' => $pID,
                        'quantity' => $_POST["quantity".$i]
                     );

       $order[] = $orderItem;
  }
```

Comment: please explain `$r` in `$i<$r+1`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `html` code you show us?

Comment: What is the `html` code, is it input or output? Before or after php execution?

Comment: before php execution.

Comment: You want two lines in your `$order`, yes? Then why do you have two loops, one `for` and one `foreach`?

Comment: It is not clear what you try to achieve. Could you provide your input in `$POST` and the desired output in `$order`? Is it only one of the `<tr />`'s that is posted or are both?

Comment: both tr are posted. the for loop is for every posted row and the foreach is for the product ID

Comment: OK, and what is the desired output? What should `$order` contain?

Answer (score 0):

A array starts from 0 not from 1. When you assign the value 1 to $i the loop is going to start from the second element from the row. Sow the solution is this.

```
for($i=0; $i<$r+1; $i++){  //r = number of rows
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_products WHERE productName = '".$_POST["product".$i]."'");     

       foreach($results as $product){
              $pID = $product->productID;
       } //I can only get the last product ID

       $orderItem = array(
                        'product' => $_POST["product".$i],
                        'productID' => $pID,
                        'quantity' => $_POST["quantity".$i]
                     );

       $order[] = $orderItem;
  }
```

this is e example. Lets say we have a array $test

```
$test = array("A","B","C","D");
```

The first element from the array is "A", and "A" is in position 0. "B" is in position 1 and so on.

Inside your foreach loop you have $pID var that save your product "ID", So the $pID is always going to have the last element from the $results. You have to put the $orderItem array inside your foreach loop.

```
foreach($results as $product){
       $pID = $product->productID;
       $orderItem = array(
                        'product' => $_POST["product".$i],
                        'productID' => $pID,
                        'quantity' => $_POST["quantity".$i]
       );
       $order[] = $orderItem;
}
```

Or you can try this

```
$results[$i] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_products WHERE productName = '".$_POST["product".$i]."'", ARRAY_A);

print_r($results);
```

Comment: The id for my input is product1, product2. That's why I started from 1. And even if I started at 0, I'm still not getting the first product ID.

Comment: The product names in your DB is like "product1","product2" or "productA","productB"  or simply "A","B"?

Comment: $r is the number of rows. in my DB it's only A, B.

Comment: can you echo the $pID inside the foreach loop?                           foreach($results as $product){
              $pID = $product->productID; echo $pID."<br>";
       }

Comment: and tell me whats you get

Comment: I'm only getting the last pID.

Comment: Ok now after your query you have to echo this. echo $_POST["product".$i]."<br>";

Comment: we need to see what you are posting

Comment: both tr are posted. And i am getting all the data from the html. I want to get the product id now.

Comment: You are getting "A" and "B" if you echo this. $_POST["product".$i]."<br>"; ??

Comment: I have update my code check it and tell me if it works